# My for loop and the dot append function is not giving me what exactly I want

Tags: python, list, function, for-loop, append

`I am working on a credit card validator that takes in up to 16 digits number which is, (the card number) and return the type of card it is. Before it gets to the part it returns the card type and other information, validation needs to be done which is where exactly I am stuck now. I created a function that prompts user to enter card number and pass it into an empty list, then created another function that would double the number from behind in a step of two which isn't working, please help me.

```
def doubled_card_number_from_behind():
    for item in range(len(empty_list) -2, 0, -2):
        double_digit_list.append(item * 2)
    return double_digit_list
```

Here is the output I am getting:

```
Hello, kindly enter card details to verify: 2345678918765432
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2]
[28, 24, 20, 16, 12, 8, 4]
```

I don't how it is getting those big values - they are not just correct.

Here is what I expect:
For example: if you enter 4326571675482146 (16 digits)
start doubling from the second last digit from behind.
4 * 2 = 8, 2 * 2 = 4, 4 * 2 = 8, 7 * 2 = 14, 1 * 2 = 2, 5 * 2 = 10, 2 * 2 = 4, 4 * 2 = 8
`

Comment: Where is *empty_list* ?

Comment: issue with the output you are getting is that you are appending the index of the item in the list to the double_digit_list instead of the value of the item.

Comment: You should be using empty_list[item] instead of item in the append() method.

Comment: the empty_list is defined up like this:
empty_list = []

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your credit number input is a 16-digit string then:

```
def doubles(ccn):
    return [int(ccn[i][0])*2 for i in range(len(ccn)-2, -2, -2)]

ccn = input('Enter credit card number: ')

if len(ccn) == 16 and ccn.isnumeric():
    print(doubles(ccn))
```

**Output:**

```
Enter credit card number: 4326571675482146
[8, 4, 8, 14, 2, 10, 4, 8]
```